# What data type to use for a method that has a List<string> parameter in java?

Tags: java

```java
public void setPersonID(List<String> personID) {
    this.personID = personID;
}

PeopleList.setPersonID();
```

I want to call the `setPersonID()` method, but I don't know what kind of data type to use for the `List<String>` parameter. Can you tell me what I should use?

Comment: Start by having a look at [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) (and [Generics Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)).  I'm kind of weirdered out that a person might have more then one id though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<T>` is an `interface` in **Java**. So you cannot instantiate it. Instead of that you might use `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`depends your requirements(`ArrayList` prefferable).  Then you can use the List interface as field type, not field instance.

//example

```
private List<String> personID = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or

```
private List<String>personID = new LinkedList<String>();
```

With this way you will use a list with different implementations, but doesn't care your implementation(you will be still use [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) methods and fields).

Then lets implement setter and getters:

```
private List<String> personID;

//mark methods publicity with your needing(public, private or protected)
public List<String> getPersonID(){
return this.personID;
}

public void setPersonID(List<String>personId){
this.personId = personId;
}

public static void Test(){
Person p = new Person();

p.setPersonId(new LinkedList<String>()); //you can initialize with LinkedList
p.setPersonId(new ArrayList<String>()); //you can Also initialize with ArrayList

//adding Item to PersonId
p.getPersonId().add("1234567890");
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Since `setPersonID()` receiving a list. So just create a list and pass to it.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("something"); // person id ?
```

That just prepares list and then you can do

```
PeopleList.setPersonID(list);
```

but it looks suspicious to me that you are passing a list to set a person id.

And before proceeding from here just [`spend some time here`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/)